# How to create Shortcut to open a specific file only in Notepad++ v 7.8.2

Tags: notepad++, textpad

I started maintaining work notes in a text document, pre Evernote/OneNote days, say in a file named worknotes.txt.  I add code, tips, tricks, queries, urls etc to this file with some comments.

I have been using TextPad where I created a shortcut to always open this file by pressing Ctrl+1.  But I can no longer use TextPad and am forced to use Notepad++ (Notepad++ v 7.8.2).

How do I create a shortcut in Notepad++?  I tried creating a macro but the macro doesn't work.  I created it by menu option Macro - Start Recording - File - Open - type the file name etc and then Stop Recording.  To test my macro, I selected menu option Macro - Playback but it didn't work.

To verify that I am recording the macro, I created other simple macros like find/replace certain string OR insert a single quote to the beginning & end of the lines in a file and all these macros run properly.

Any thoughts/tips/pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a Macro you may want to use `Run` from the main menu to open your file and add a shortcut for this as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

---

**Update: Steps for adding shortcut**

From the main menu goto **Run > Run** or press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key. Copy the following (previously adapted) call into the text box and **SAVE**

```
"$(NPP_FULL_FILE_PATH)" "d:\_temp\my-file.txt"
```

- `$(NPP_FULL_FILE_PATH)` is the full drive, folder, and executable for the active instance of notepad.exe; the quotes are needed if there are spaces in Notepad++'s path.
- replace `"d:\_temp\my-file.txt"` with the correct path to your file; if there are spaces in the filename, it must have the quotes around it.

In the next dialog name it **Open My File** or similar, assign keyboard shortcut e.g <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> click **OK** and **Run** to run it immediately or **Cancel**.

[image]

Now the Run menu will contain **Open My File**, and that menu entry (and keyboard shortcut) will quickly open the desired file.

[image]

And `%AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml` will contain lines like this:

```xml
<UserDefinedCommands>
    <Command name="Get PHP help" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="112">https://www.php.net/$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
    <Command name="Wikipedia Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="114">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
    <Command name="Open my File" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="120">&quot;C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe&quot;</Command>
</UserDefinedCommands>
```

Comment: how do i add my file with the shortcut, we will get like shown in the image once we assign a shortcut to a file right ?

Comment: @Ramesh Thiyagarajan - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go is to open once the file in Notepad++ and **never** close it, just save the changes. Then, when you close Notepad++ and reopen it sometimes later, the file is allways present in Notepad++.

For this to work you have to enable `Remember current session for next launch`:

> Settings > Preferences > Backup > `Remember current session for next launch`